# C# Can not access object from a class

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor

I'm trying to access an object `TextBox` from a class. I tried using constructors but nothing happened. It was working until I added panels and added more forms.

My Main Form that loads my form:

```
public partial class MenuForm : Form
{
    public MenuForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ConfigForm Config = new ConfigForm();
    GeneralForm General = new GeneralForm();

    private void Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load of Config Form
        Config.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
        Config.Show();

       //Load of General Form
        General.Show();
        General.TopLevel = false;
        Config.Controls["panel1"].Controls.Add(General);
     }
}
```

Here is my config form:

```
public partial class ConfigForm : Form
{
    private ConfigFormHelper confighelper = null;
    private GeneralFormHelper generalhelper = new GeneralFormHelper();

    public ConfigForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        generalhelper.LoadTemplate();
    }
}
```

Here is my general helper class:

```
class GeneralFormHelper
{
    GeneralForm generalform2 = new GeneralForm();

    public void LoadConfig()
    {
        this.generalform2.txtDSN1.Text = "test";
    }
}
```

There's no error but `txtDSN1` doesn't get the "test" text.

`txtDSN1` is on the `public` modifier.

Comment: You are setting the textbox of another instance, different than the instance which you currently see. Look at this line in MainForm: `GeneralForm General = new GeneralForm();` which you showed `Config.Show();` and the other one in GeneralFormHelper: `GeneralForm generalform2 = new GeneralForm();`

Comment: is this correct? `public GeneralForm myForm; 
public GeneralFormHelper(GeneralForm form)
        {
            this.myForm = form;
        }
`
is this correct?

Comment: Rework your design. As @RezaAghaei mentioned, you have multiple instances for `GeneralForm` and also `GeneralFormHelper.LoadConfig()` doesn't seem to be used in the code you provided.

Comment: @FatalError Yes it can be a solution.

Comment: but what to put on parameter in my config form? 
`private GeneralFormHelper generalhelper = new GeneralFormHelper();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be your `GeneralFormHelper` with method `GetGeneralForm()`

```
 class GeneralFormHelper
    {
        GeneralForm generalform2;
        public void GetGeneralForm(GeneralForm g)
        {
          this.generalform2 = g;
        }
        public void LoadConfig()
        {
          this.generalform2.txtDSN1.Text = "test";
        }
    }
```

this will be your `ConfigForm class :

```
public partial class ConfigForm : Form
{
    private ConfigFormHelper confighelper = null;
    private GeneralFormHelper generalhelper;


    public ConfigForm(GeneralForm g) /* your Constructor get the General */
    {
        this.generalhelper = g;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        generalhelper.LoadTemplate();
    }
}
```

and finally your `MenuForm` class :

```
public partial class MenuForm : Form
{
    public MenuForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    GeneralForm General = new GeneralForm();

    ConfigForm Config = new ConfigForm(General); /* you send General */

    private void Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load of Config Form
        Config.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
        Config.Show();

       //Load of General Form
        General.Show();
        General.TopLevel = false;
        Config.Controls["panel1"].Controls.Add(General);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks btw, it says General does not exist in the current context

Comment: it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object to this.generalform2.txtDSN1.Text = "test";

Comment: u have to send your objects via methods where ever you want

Comment: but what if I want it do be dynamic? because I'm not just gonna use General Form only, i have other forms that will use Config

Comment: i hope get your mean , for using other types u can use generics

Comment: sure :) u can use this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) and this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm) generic is a general type like T that u defined it and say i want specify this T type later when i want to create or use this class (or method). see these links to get better info with examples

Comment: btw what's the best practice have an single instance?

Comment: if you want to have just a single instance there is a design pattern called [Singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) that made you to have just one instance not more whenever you try to create an instance from a class

Comment: btw , try to understand [scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) in a language completely because most of the problem in this question related to scopes

Answer (score 1):

This LoadConfig function of GeneralFormHelper is never called.

```
public void LoadConfig()
{
this.generalform2.txtDSN1.Text = "test";
}
```

This code in the ConfigForm calls LoadTemplate instead of LoadConfig

```
private void comboTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    generalhelper.LoadTemplate();
}
```

So I guess your first problem is just a typo, and you just need to match either LoadConfig or LoadTemplate.

The second problem is that the LoadTemplate (or LoadConfig) is called only when the SelectedIndexChanged event is raised. So, until then, you won't get the "test" text.

Comment: I'm sorry there's another function before LoadTemplate which is LoadConfig.. just didn't need  provide that.. thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the object from a class you need to do it like this..

```
     In a class:



     using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace getObjectFromaClass
    {

    class Class1
    {
       public static TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();

        public void getText()
        {
            try
            {
                txt1.Text = "this is my text";
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                string x = er.Message;
            }

        }
    }
     }




    In a form:

    namespace getObjectFromaClass
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Class1 cls1 = new Class1();
        public Form1()
        {

            textBox1=Class1.txt1;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cls1.getText();
            textBox1.Text = Class1.txt1.Text;
        }
    }
     }
```